# KDEConnect for Ubuntu

Tags: unity, android, kde

Is there an app in Ubuntu that provides the same integration with Android phones as [KDEConnect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect)?

Now that KDE is a framework it mightn't have the same impact of installing libs into my Ubuntu install as it used.to but if there was something designed that would be better.

Comment: If you want filesharing with your android phone then samba would be suited best for that.

Comment: You could investigate Linconnect but I had an unmet dependency problem with it and hoped for something similar without adding an entire KDE environment.

Comment: From [here](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect#Installation): If you are a GNOME user you might prefer [GSConnect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/), a GNOME shell extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 2017, you can use kdeconnect on Unity if you install kde-connect indicator. To do that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-kdeconnect
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To share files between your PC and Android, I use [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), no
   PC client needed.
2. To Control your laptop from your PC, I use [Splashtop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.remote.pad.v2), The Ubuntu client is available in the software center, I'd download it personally [from Splashtop.com.](http://www.splashtop.com/linux#download) My friend likes to use [teamviewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) instead, the Ubuntu client is available on Teamviewer.com

Note that I have never shared web pages, although it might be possible, I prefer using [pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro), it has an extension for [dolphin browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dolphin.addons.pocket) if you use it, maybe other browsers as well, and an extension for every PC browser.

Comment: I use Airdroid and Pocket All the time, splashtop is a nice suggestion. Kdeconnect had just a deeper level of integration when hooked up your messages and sms show on the laptop, it pauses music on the laptop when this happens. It's just done well and I had hoped to avoid kdelibs

Comment: @sayth Well I tried installing kdeconnect on my xubuntu, didn't work, I guess it only works on a kde desktop

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu supports KDE services, but you may need to check the checkbox in Startup Apps to activate KDE services. Then you can install kdeconnect indicator, and then you will be able to install kdeconnect on your Android device to transfer stuff from the phone.